# How to split data 70:30 and get a different range of data everytime you split it

Tags: r, random-forest, data-partitioning

I'm currently using R to do feature selection through the use of Random Forest regression. I want to split my data 70:30, which is easy enough to do. However, I want to be able to do this 10 times, with each 10 times obtaining a different set of examples from the one before.

```
> trainIndex<- createDataPartition(lipids$RT..seconds., p=0.7, list=F)
> lipids.train <- lipids[trainIndex, ]
> lipids.test <- lipids[-trainIndex, ]
```

This is what I'm doing at the moment, and it works great for splitting my data 70:30. But when I do it again , I get the same 70% of the data in my training set, and the same 30% of the data in my test data. I know this is how createDataPartition works, but is there way of making it so that I get a different 70% of the data the next time I perform it?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used `createDataPartition` but couldn't you just use `sample` to get random index values and subset for those indices?

Comment: In the future, please include the packages you're using since `createDataPartition` is not in base R.  Did you find the `times` argument?

Comment: @Codoremifa I've not come across sample, however it does seem to be the answer to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, please include the packages you're using since `createDataPartition` is not in base R. I'm assuming you're using the `caret` package.  If that is correct, did you find the `times` argument?

```
trainIndex<- createDataPartition(lipids$RT..seconds., p=0.7, list=F, times=10)
```

As mentioned in the comment, you can just as simply use `sample`:

```
sample(seq_along(lipids$RD..seconds), as.integer(0.7 * nrow(lipids)))
```

And `sample` will choose a different random seed each time it is run, so you will get different orders.

Comment: Will do sorry! And I am using caret yes. I have come across the times argument, however when I do:- 'lipids.train <- lipids[trainIndex, ]'
I get 10 folds of 70% of my data all in one, and I don't know how to use the times argument to allow me to make a random forest model 10 times using 10 different subsets of the data, but the sample method seems to work perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
n <- as.integer(length(data[,1])*0.7)
data_70 <- data[sample(nrow(data),n), ]
data_30 <- anti_join(data, data_70)
```